# NetworkAvailabilityChanged Socket Error

Tags: c#, windows, sockets, networking, tablet

I'm new to creating applications to target tablets. I've got a project where the tablet is likely to not have a network connection at any given point. I'd like to monitor the network availability status and enable/disable capabilities on UI accordingly. I've done some reading around and found out about 
using System.Net.NetworkInformation. From what I've read on it, it seems like what I want to use, so I added it per the articles/posts I've read.

I'm running 64-bit Win7 Enterprise SP1 using Visual Studio 2013 on .NET 4.0. The machine I'm running on is a Intel i3-2120. The network adapter is an Intel 82579LM.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows.Media.Effects;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace GWL{

public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Loaded += delegate { MainWindowLoaded(); };
    }

    private void MainWindowLoaded()
    {
        NetworkIsAvailable = NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
        try
        {                
            NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged += delegate { NetworkIsAvailable = NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable(); };
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

When processing comes down to the NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged listener, I get the following socket error:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException Error Code 10022: "An invalid argument was supplied" at System.Net.SafeCloseSocketAndEvent.CreateWSASocketWithEvent(AddressFamily addressFamily, SocketType socketType, ProtocolType protocolType, Boolean autoReset, Boolean signaled) in System.
```

Complete Error Message:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException occurred
  _HResult=-2147467259
  _message=An invalid argument was supplied
  HResult=-2147467259
  IsTransient=false
  Message=An invalid argument was supplied
  Source=System
  ErrorCode=10022
  NativeErrorCode=10022
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.SafeCloseSocketAndEvent.CreateWSASocketWithEvent(AddressFamily addressFamily, SocketType socketType, ProtocolType protocolType, Boolean autoReset, Boolean signaled)
  InnerException:
```

Is there something I'm missing in assigning the delegate to NetworkAvailabilityChanged, or further configuration that I've missed? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Update**: This problem seems to related to the fact that project was on a network drive. I moved it to local storage and the error does not occur. When moved back to the network drive, it shows up again.

Comment: Are you saying that you get that exception on the statement `NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged += delegate { NetworkIsAvailable = NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable(); };`? I don't think subscribing to an event should _ever_ throw an exception (except possibly `OutOfMemoryException` in _very_ unusual cases). What environment are you running under? Windows 8.1? Windows RT? What version of .NET? It sounds like you're either dealing with a bug in .NET, or a "by design" restriction in the environment. But without more specifics, it's hard to say.

Comment: I'm working on Win7 in Visual Studio 2015 using .NET 4.0. The error is occurring on subscribing the event. My current implementation has is using the delegate. I've attempted to use a NetworkedAvailabilityChangedEventHandler as well, but got the same result. 


This isn't a critical path for me, but it would leave my interface looking unfinished, and I can't have that. If there's any more information I can supply, let me know. I can reproduce the error without a problem.

Comment: The call to GetIsNetworkAvailable() above the event handler works without a problem. Even without that call, the event handler still produces an error. I thought there might be something being left open after GetIsNetworkAvailable(), but that does not seem to be the case.

Comment: What is the full stack trace? And not that the GUI framework should make a difference, but which one are you using here? It looks like Winforms...can you confirm? A [minimal-but- complete code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful.

Comment: Please put the full stack trace in the question, where it can be formatted in a readable way. For what it's worth, I wrote a simple program (based on the code you provided), in Forms and WPF both, and they both run fine on Windows 7 and Windows 8.1

Comment: Also, you might as well put into the question any other environment detail you can think of: hardware make/model, CPU, network adapter, etc.

Comment: Thanks, Peter. Quick update: I did the same thing you did, and it works. I'm guessing something in my original project is hosed up. That's not a fun prospect.

Comment: Maybe not. But it's actually really good news, because it means you have a model that fails and a model that works. Comparing the two will eventually uncover what's wrong. Just start taking stuff out of the one that fails, until it works. :) BTW, is that really the _entire_ stack trace? It's extremely unusual to have a stack trace with only one stack frame in it.

Comment: That's the plan, when I have some time to get past the code. I've got to get the critical functionality finished before I worry about that too much. Thanks for your help. If I find a fix, I'll be sure to post it. I hate when people leave questions unanswered. "I found the problem and fixed it!" and then no elaboration.